# My button isn't spreading across my container

Tags: react-native, flexbox, scrollview, container-view

I am trying to set my button style that way, it will be spread across my View. Currently its creating white border on the left and on the bottom of my button (see attached screenshot).

[image]

My code:

```
let {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
        let photoWidth = width/4;

return (
            <View style={{width: width, height: 500}}>
                <ScrollView style={{width: width, height: height}}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: width, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
                    {
                        this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
                            return (
                                <SelectedPhoto
                                    key={i}
                                    index={i}
                                    style={{
                                        width: photoWidth,
                                        height: photoWidth,
                                    }}
                                    limit={this.state.supportLength}
                                    photo={p}
                                    onSelectPhoto={this.onSelectPhoto}
                                    onDeselectPhoto={this.onDeselectPhoto}
                                />
                            );
                        })
                    }
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
                <View style={{ flexDirection:"row", flexWrap: 'wrap', width: width }}>
                    <Button

                        onPress={this.onNext}  
                        containerViewStyle={{width: width}}
                        backgroundColor={Colors.red}
                        title='NEXT' />
                </View>             
            </View>
        );
```

Comment: try to add `position: 'absolute', right:40, top:300` in your `Button style`, and set `height` of `View` to max, before `<ScrollView>` and delete `style` in <ScrollView>

Comment: @flix cant you please again include code? I tried to implement the changes ...its putting the button in the middle of the screen

Comment: just change the `right` and `top` value to go to your bottom screen, it's mean your `button` will `fixed`, or you won't let the `button` `fixed`?

Comment: It works on my android, the question is how will it look in other devices? I tried to run it on android studio ...it did not load the page . I need also to test it on ios

Comment: actually, you need to set the `value` of `right` or `top` in percentage of screen size, so every time the app opened in different screen size, the value would be dynamic, depending on percentage of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I consider `Button` component you used from `react-native`. Just remove wrapper flex you added as you set `width` to it.

```
<Button
   onPress={this.onNext}  
   containerViewStyle={{width: width}}
   backgroundColor={Colors.red}
   title='NEXT' />
```

Comment: it didnt fix the issue ...it stayed the same

Comment: Bottom white part is because of the height you provided to Upper View as 500. Can you please make expo project and share link